# Как в DevExpress называется свойство для показа значка в виде трёх точек в столбце?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, devexpress

Не могу найти определённое свойство в DevExpress. Применение заключается в том, что при включённом этом свойстве в клетках определённого столбца появляется значок в виде трёх точек, при нажатии на этот значок открывается отдельное окно, либо превью с таблицей. Подскажите, где искать эту функцию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположу, что это решение вашей проблемы

```
<dxg:GridControl ...>  
    <dxg:GridControl.Columns>  
        <dxg:GridColumn ...>  
            <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>  
                <dxe:ButtonEditSettings AllowDefaultButton="True" />  
            </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>  
        </dxg:GridColumn>  
    </dxg:GridControl.Columns>  
    <dxg:GridControl.View>  
        <dxg:TableView EditorButtonShowMode="ShowAlways" />  
    </dxg:GridControl.View>  
</dxg:GridControl>
```

Вот ссылка на подробный ответ на форуме: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T258236/buttonedit-three-dots-as-content